# Combine all color passes

Tags: compositing-nodes, color, render-passes

So i'm trying to merge 4 color passes (DiffuseColor, GlossyColor, TranslucentColor and SubsurfceColor) so i can get 1 Combined color map. Is this possible? If so, how cand i do it?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of: [How to make original full-pass image from separate passes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45754/how-to-make-original-full-pass-image-from-separate-passes) or [Correctly re-combine ALL render passes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80469/correctly-re-combine-all-render-passes)